# Error with ThreadLocal example

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn how to use Java and came across this tutorial from java2s.com. It's dealing with ThreadLocal variables. I tried plugging it into my compiler but it stutters at the `new Thread(Main::run).start();` section. I can't figure out why it doesn't want to compile. I'm not proficient enough with Java to know if I shouldn't be using that method to create a new thread or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the full code example.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Thread(Main::run).start();
     new Thread(Main::run).start();
     }//from  ww  w .  j a  v  a2s  . co  m
  public static void run() {
     int counter = 3;
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "  generated counter:  " + counter);
     for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        CallTracker.call();
     }
  }
}
class CallTracker {
     private static ThreadLocal<Integer> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();
     public static void call() {
     int counter = 0;
     Integer counterObject = threadLocal.get();

     if (counterObject == null) {
        counter = 1;
     } else {
        counter = counterObject.intValue();
        counter++;
     }
     threadLocal.set(counter);
     String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
     System.out.println("Call  counter for " + threadName + "  = " + counter);
   }
}
```

Comment: `ThreadLocal` isn't actually pertinent to the problem you're having. Try getting rid of `CallTracker` and the body of `run()`, and see if you still have the same problem; I'm guessing you will. This is a much smaller piece of code for you to ask for help with.

Answer (score 1):

This code is compilable and will run. I even ran it myself to validate...cause why not.

The reason you're running into a problem is likely that your compiler is set to interpret java prior to java 1.8. The part "Main::run" is a new functionality starting in 1.8. Even if you are using a 1.8 jdk your compiler might be set to compile to an earlier version.

Check what level your ide is using and make sure it's set appropriately.